# Problem implementing search on my flutter app through cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I want to implement search on my flutter app through cloud firestore database (by 'NAME' field of documents). I came across with the query below but sadly this query is case sensitive.
If I want to search 'Apple', then I will have to type 'Apple'. Typing 'apple' or 'APplE' won't give any result.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('test')
                        .where(
                          'NAME',
                          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchVal,
                          isLessThan: searchVal
                                  .substring(0, searchVal.length - 1) +
                              String.fromCharCode(searchVal
                                          .codeUnitAt(searchVal.length - 1) +
                                      1),
                        )
                        .snapshots()
```

Please suggest any way to make this searching efficient and not case-sensitive.

Comment: A common practice is to add another field whose value is the name field  coerced to all lower case and to do the same to the input search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64540229/16929894), Firestore cannot currently perform case-insensitive queries. In this case, the comment on your post applies, so you should create an alternate name field in Firestore that contains all lower case names. From the client side, all queries should be made lower case with a function such as [toLowerCase()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-core/String/toLowerCase.html) so that letter cases completely match on both ends.